# Retrieve Azure storage account key using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In my release pipeline I'm using a Azure CLI to transfer my build files to a Azure storage blob:

```
call az storage blob upload-batch --source "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" --destination "$web" --account-key "****QxjclDGftOY/agnqUDzwNe/gOIAzsQ==" --account-name "*****estx"
```

This works, but I want to retrieve the `account-key` dynamically.

When I use:

```
az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n ****estx
```

I get a array with 2 objects, both holding a key value:

```
[
    {
    "keyName": "key1",
    "permissions": "Full",
    "value": "f/eybpcl*****************Vm9uT1PwFC1D82QxjclDGftOY/agnqUDzwNe/gOIAzsQ=="
    },
    {
    "keyName": "key2",
    "permissions": "Full",
    "value": "bNM**********L6OxAemK1U2oudW5WGRQW++/bzD6jVw=="
    }
]
```

How do I use one of the two keys in my `upload-batch` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a Azure Powershell task (version 4) that does:

```
az login -u **** -p ****
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=storageKey;]az storage account keys list -g ***** -n ***** --query [0].value -o tsv"
$key = az storage account keys list -g ***** -n **** --query [0].value -o tsv
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=something;]$key"
```

Then I can use the `something` variable in my Azure CLI task:

```
call az storage blob upload-batch --source "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" --destination "$web" --account-key $(something) --account-name "*****"
```

And this works. You'll probably need to put the -u and -p in a variable though.

@Charles thanks a lot for this line `(az storage account keys list -g **** -n ****estx --query [0].value -o tsv)` !

Answer (score 18):

For your issue, if you just want one of the two keys for example, the first one. You can set a variable with the key as the value like this:

```
key=$(az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n ****estx --query [0].value -o tsv)
```

And then use the variable `key` in the other command like this:

```
call az storage blob upload-batch --source "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" --destination "$web" --account-key $key --account-name "*****estx"
```

Or you can just put the command which gets the key in the other command directly like this:

```
call az storage blob upload-batch --source "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" --destination "$web" --account-key $(az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n ****estx --query [0].value -o tsv) --account-name "*****estx"
```

**Update**

According to what you said, it seems you run the command in the windows command prompt, it's different from the Linux shell and PowerShell. You cannot set the environment variable with the value that the output of a command. You can do that like this:

```
az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n ****estx --query [0].value -o tsv > key.txt
set /P key=<key.txt
az storage blob upload-batch --source "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" --destination "$web" --account-key %key% --account-name "*****estx"
```

And it seems you just can quote the environment variable as %variable_name%, so it seems it's a wrong way to use `"$web"` in your command.

Comment: I'm using a `Azure CLI` task, it's different from a `Azure Powershell`. I've tried your solution but I'm getting a `'key' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` and a `'[0].value' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: @PeterBoomsma In both two commands, the `[0].value -o tsv) --account-name "*****estx"` is on the same line as the command. You can try it again. And what is the host you run the CLI command?

Comment: When I run the second command I get `    D:\a\r1\a>call az storage blob upload-batch --source "D:\a\r1\a/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" --destination "$web" --account-key $(az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n ****testx --query [0].value -o tsv) --account-name "****testx" 
    --account-name was unexpected at this time.` The agent is `Hosted VS2017`.

Comment: just running `az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n embracesuitetestx --query [0].value -o tsv` does show the correct key. so at least that's working :). But I can't use that in the function, `az: error: unrecognized arguments: storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n` i guess that's why the `( )` are for.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma It seems you run the CLI command is windows system and in command prompt. It's different from the Linux and PowerShell. I suggest if you just want to run the Azure CLI command, you can choose a Linux Host.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma I have updated the answer and you can take a look at it.

Comment: No it does not. There wasn't any feedback, the release would kinda keep running until I canceled it. I can't understand why it's so difficult to move some data to a variable.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to :). I'm going to give up and go through the management API to retrieve the data.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Because you run the Azure CLI in Windows. It's recommended running in Linux. PowerShell is more suitable in Windows.